# Questions that ask for a specific type of answer

Tags: discussion, questions

I just wanted to clarify if it's okay to ask questions on Stackoverflow that specifically asked that the answer meet certain requirements regardless of what anybody elses opinion of that would be? And if the answer didn't meet those requirements would I still have to accept it?

For example:

In wordpress.stackexchange.com if I asked a question and specified I wanted a coded solution rather than a solution provided by 3rd party plugin, is that acceptable? Or should I still accept the plugin solution if someone chose to ignore it.

Comment: If your question belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ then it has its [own Meta site](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/) - generally speaking, there is close reason "Too Localized" that might apply in your case. You should ask yourself - "will this be useful to other people with code similar to my own?"

Comment: You should ask yourself - "will this be useful to other people with code similar to my own?" > oh, the irony. It would be useful to other plugin developers :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the meta site for wordpress. I don't think its specific to any stackexchange site but I did ask because of a question I asked there that devolved into something rather pointless. Someone even edited out my requirement of not wanting to use a plugin. If someone wants to move my question there they can.

Comment: Not familiar with wordpress very much however just know that every StackExchange site has its own Meta site, while this one is the "main", being also the "Meta of Meta" for global stuff of the whole network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course that is acceptable. Those requirements are often the reason for the question.

Not the same as saying your requirements will make sense to people, but still...

and of course you don't need to accept *any* answer.

However, I would just recommend being open to suggestions. Sometimes people will suggest another way around your requirements.

DISCLAIMER: This answer is given in general, with *no* knowledge of any specific question/answer.

Comment: I'd rather not point to any specific question/answer at this point. I think its a pretty straight forward question and I don't want to dilute the conversation with anything external (I think)

Comment: @EddyR Very often, specific examples are helpful in answering a question like this (which is why you were asked for a link in the comments to your question). *In this particular case*, though, I thought a general answer would be helpful, also. If you are having *significant* problems with how any user is responding to your content - beyond what you can simply ignore - consider flagging those responses for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask for whatever kind of solution you want, and you can make a choice on your own criteria when deciding which answer, if any, you want to accept.

On the other hand the people answering the questions can, as long as its on topic, post any kind of answer they want and so if someone's question is asking for a less than optimal solution then they can try and explain why the scenario posed in such a question is flawed and try to lead the discussion towards a non-flawed solution.